# pandas HDF select does not recognise column name

Tags: python, csv, pandas, hdfstore

I'm trying to process a large (2gb) csv file on a machine with only 4gb of RAM (don't ask) to produce a different, formatted csv containing a subset of data that needs some processing.  I'm reading the file and creating a HDFstore that I query later for the data that I require for output.  Everything works except that I cant retrieve data from the store using Term - error message comes back that PLOT is not a column name.  Individual variables look fine and the store is what I expect I just can't see where the error is. (nb pandas v14 and numpy1.9.0).  Very new to this so apologies for the clunky code.

```
#wibble wobble -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# short version
def filesport():
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from pandas.io.pytables import Term

    Location = r"CL_short.csv"
    store = pd.HDFStore('blarg.h5')

    maxlines = sum(1 for line in open (Location))
    print maxlines
 #set chunk small for test file   
    chunky=4
    plotty =pd.DataFrame(columns=['PLOT'])
    dfdum=pd.DataFrame(columns=['PLOT', 'mDate', 'D100'])

#read file in chunks to avoid RAM blowing up    
    bucket = pd.read_csv(Location, iterator=True, chunksize=chunky, usecols=   ['PLOT','mDate','D100'])

    for chunk in bucket:
        store.append('wibble', chunk, format='table', data_columns=['PLOT','mDate','D100'], ignore_index=True)

#retrieve plot numbers and select unique items
    plotty = store.select('wibble', "columns = ['PLOT']")
    plotty.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

#iterate through unique plots to retrieve data and put in dataframe for output
    for index, row in plotty.iterrows():
        dfdum = store.select('wibble', [Term('PLOT', '=', plotty.iloc[index]['PLOT'])])
#process dfdum for output to new csv

    print("successful completion")
filesport()
```

Comment: I'll answer my own question in case somebody else encounters the problem and finds themselves in this dark, lonely corner of the web. The problem is that Term needs to be a string and the numerical part of Term is a numerical variable not a string. I couldn't get the str function to work within the Term() part however this did workfor index, row in plotty.iterrows():
        condition = 'PLOT =' + str(plotty.iloc[index]['PLOT'])
        dfdum = store.select('wibble', [Term(condition)]).

Comment: for index, row in plotty.iterrows():
        condition = 'PLOT =' + str(plotty.iloc[index]['PLOT'])
        dfdum = store.select('wibble', [Term(condition)])

Answer (score 0):

Final listing for those that wish to fight through the tumbleweed to reach here and are similarly bemused by processing large .csv files and the various methods of trying to retrieve/process data.  The biggest problem was getting the sytax of the pytables Term right.  Despite several examples indicating that it was possible to use 'A >20' etc this never worked for me. I set up a string condition containing the Term query and this worked (it is in the documentation TBF).
Also found it easier to query the HDF to retrieve unique items direct from the store  in a list which could then be sorted and iterated through to retrieve data plot by plot.  Note that I wanted the final csv file to have plot and then all the D100 data in date order, hence the pivot at the end.
Reading the csv file in chunks meant that each plot retrieved from the store had a header and this got written to the final csv which messed things up.  I'm sure there's a more elegant way of only writing one header than the one I've shown here.
It works, takes about 2 hours to process the data and produce the final csv file (initial file 2GB, 30+million lines, data for 100,000+ unique plots, machine has 4GB of RAM but running 32-bit which means that only 2.5GB of RAM was available).
Good luck if you have a similar problem, and I hope you find this useful

```
#wibble wobble -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def filesport():
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from pandas.io.pytables import Term

    print (pd.__version__)
    print (np.__version__)

    Location = r"conliq_med.csv"
    store = pd.HDFStore('blarg.h5')

    maxlines = sum(1 for line in open (Location))
    print maxlines
    chunky=100000

#read file in chunks to avoid RAM blowing up select only needed columns
    bucket = pd.read_csv(Location, iterator=True, chunksize=chunky, usecols= ['PLOT','mDate','D100'])

    for chunk in bucket:
        store.append('wibble', chunk, format='table', data_columns=['PLOT','mDate','D100'], ignore_index=True)

#retrieve unique plots and sort 
    plotty = store.select_column('wibble', 'PLOT').unique()
    plotty.sort()
#set flag for writing file header
    i=0

#iterate through unique plots to retrieve data and put in dataframe for output
    for item in plotty:
        condition = 'PLOT =' + str(item)
        dfdum = store.select('wibble', [Term(condition)])
        dfdum["mDate"]= pd.to_datetime(dfdum["mDate"], dayfirst=True)
        dfdum.sort(columns=["PLOT", "mDate"], inplace=True)
        dfdum["mDate"] = dfdum["mDate"].map(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y - %m"))
        dfdum=dfdum.pivot("PLOT", "mDate", "D100")

#only print one header to file 
        if i ==0:
             dfdum.to_csv("CL_OP.csv", mode='a')  
             i=1
        else:
             dfdum.to_csv("CL_OP.csv", mode='a', header=False)

    print("successful completion")

filesport()
```